# Cloning development environment across machines

Tags: python

So I'm doing a bit of Python development work right now, and I was wondering if it was possible to "clone" my entire development environment, specifically the Python interpreter and all the libraries I have installed, to my laptop. I currently use GitHub to store and sync my files across machines, and I use Sublime Text as my main code editor so I can just install it on both machines by hand, but I don't want to have to hunt down and re-install every library and their dependencies on the new machine because I don't remember everything I might've installed and doing it by hand might not get me everything I need.

My first guess would be to just copy/paste the Python folder from my main PC to my laptop, but I have no idea how to synchronize it so that updates and changes made to one side can be brought over to the other without hassle.

How do more experienced programmers/developers handle working on large projects across multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is keep a [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for each project on each machine and check a [`requirements.txt`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html) file into your Git repository, and do

```
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install -r /path/to/project/requirements.txt
```

each time you add or change a library.